# Can I replace a 10uf/6.3v capacitor with a 470uF/16 capacitor

Tags: capacitor, comparison

I am trying to repair a tivoli music system BT.  The problem is the schematic is one version out of date.  The schematic shows a 10uf/6.3v but the board with a newer version number has a 470uf/16v capacitor soldered on.

The capacitor is bulged and the continuity test failed so I am thinking replace with the same but could this be a mistake made by the manufacturer.

Its been years since taking electronics and my understanding getting fainter by the day.  Advice would help.  Txs,

Comment: Without seeing the schematic, it's not entirely possible to say for sure. But there is a huge difference in size between those two ratings. Does the circuit board clearly make good room for the one that was installed? If so, I'd say that the value is what it should be. It could be that the old schematic is wrongly labeled. That happens. But if it looks like the area is over-stuffed on your board, maybe the schematic is right. Is this at the output of a DC supply rail? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Please explain how the continuity test is relevant here

Comment: Without knowing the exact circuit it is impossible to say.  However, the odds of it being a manufacturer mistake are very low.  Does the board have a silkscreened legend?  If so, is there a circle around the cap?  If so, are the circles around other electrolytic caps significantly larger than their components, or a tight fit.  That should tell you if the wrong (physical) sized part is there, because a 10 uF and 470 uF cap are way different.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what the capacitor is used for.

> Can I replace a 10uf/6.3v capacitor with a 470uF/16 capacitor?

The general answer to this question is **NO**. But in many situations, you surely can.

I'd say your best bet is to assume that the manufacturer knew what they were doing, and replace the capacitor with whatever you take out.
Especially since the other way around, replacing 470µF/16V with 10µF/6.3V is rarely ever safe unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: The board has 470uF/16V soldered in and bulging.  The schematic has 10uF/6.3v showing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically only capacitors that are under stress are failing by bulging and leaking. In most cases these are caps that have a lot of ripple current through them in high temperatures, such as output or input capacitor of a switch mode regulator.

So as nobody knows what the capacitor does in the circuit, it is definitely not a good idea to randomly switch a 470uF 16V cap to a 10uF 6.3V cap.

If the voltage is over 6.3V then a 6.3V cap could even explode if the circuit requires a 16V cap. There must be a reason why there was a 470uF 16V cap. If it is an output cap for a switching regulator, the total capacitance will be too low and the regulator output could become unstable, have a lot of ripple, or overvoltages from switching peaks that destroy the rest of the device.

Now it might be that they replaced the original cap with a 16V 470uF cap because a good properly selected 10uF 6.3V cap with low ESR would have been suitable, but it costs too much or cheap 10uF 6.3V caps did not work so they put a normal cheap 470uF 16V cap in place, which has low enough ESR due to size and enough capacitance to keep ripple down at low enough levels.

So no, if you don't know what the cap does in the circuit or even the type of the cap (standard, low ESR, or high end polymer type), there's no way you know if you can replace it with one that has smaller capacitance and voltage ratings, as you don't even know which 470uF 16V capacitor would be suitable.

Comment: I would love to share the schematic but they asked me to sign a NDA not to distribute the plan.  I could add a screen shot of the board area and a clip of the specific area from the schematic help in this discussion.  To me that seems reasonable.

Comment: How can I send a couple of screenshots in this forum